# Passing a numpy array FROM C++ using boost python

Tags: python, boost, numpy

I need to pass a numpy array to a python function from C++.
The code is below.
The python side:

```
import numpy as np
import  convert as cv

def f(x):
  x[0] = 5.
  return len(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  y = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
  x = cv.func_n(f, y)
  print x
```

The C++ side:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;
double func_n(PyObject* f, numeric::array &x)
{
  std::cerr << "Inside func_n\n";
  return boost::python::call<double>(f, boost::ref(x));
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(convert)
{
  numeric::array::set_module_and_type("numpy", "ndarray");

  def("func_n", &func_n);

}
```

What the C++ code is supposed to do is to take a python functopn and a numpy array as two arguments and then pass the numpy array to the python function.
The error I an getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mm.py", line 11, in <module>
    x = cv.func_n(f, y)
TypeError: No Python class registered for C++ class class boost::python::numeric::array
```

Why? Do I have to register the module during the recursive call of the interpreter and, if so, how?

Comment: Continuation: using return boost::python::call<double>(f, x); instead of return boost::python::call<double>(f, boost::ref(x)); helps and the code works fine. What does boost::ref(x) do? I as under the impression that boost::python::call copies the arguments. Turned out it doesn't. Where can this be clarified?

Answer (score 0):

`boost::ref(x)` returns a [`boost::reference_wrapper<T>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/ref.html), which allows you to pass references to by-value functions.

The [boost::python::call docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/v2/callbacks.html#argument_handling) show that arguments are treated differently based on their type. If the arg is a `boost::reference_wrapper<T>`, it effectively passes a reference to `x` down to Python.

So, in the code above, you were passing the reference to your numeric::array to Python. The function you're calling from Python also accepts a reference.

Now I'm not sure about this, but I suspect that since you were never actually passing a numeric::array between Python/C++, boost::python decided not to wrap it or create converters (since you're really just passing around addresses). This may be why you saw no Python class registered for the numeric::array type.